# neo4j get one root node by it's relations

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm new to neo4j, and looks like something is missing in the query.

I've two documents, in a MongoDB collection, as fallows:

**Doc 1:**

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('5ef0d7421e4f0a0006b717b6'),
    id: 1,
    type: 'Person',
    name: 'Andrea',
    books: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Flow My Tears, the Policeman Said',
            released: 1974
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: 'The man in the High Castle',
            released: 1962
        }
    ]
}
```

**Doc 2**

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('5ef0d8981e4f0a0006b717b7'),
    id: 1,
    type: 'Person',
    name: 'Bruno',
    books: [
        {
            id: 3,
            title: 'The Bold with long hair',
            released: 2008
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: 'The man in the High Castle',
            released: 1962
        }
    ]
}
```

By making this query, I got the result in the picture bellow.

```
CALL apoc.mongodb.get('mongodb://mongo:neo4j@mongo:27017', 'test', 'books',{}, true) YIELD value

CALL apoc.graph.fromDocument(value,
{
    write: false,
    skipValidation: true,
    mappings: {
      `$`: 'Person:Reader{name}',
      `$.books`: 'Book{!title, id}'
    }
}
) YIELD graph AS g1
return g1
```

[image]

Everything looks fine, however I was expecting to see **Bruno and Andrea** linked by the same book **The man in the High Castle** (id: 2).

What am I missing?

Comment: try writing back the results and investigating stored results. You are currently just previewing what the results would look like and maybe because of the virtual graph the nodes are not merged into a single one